# Creating .dll from .h and .lib in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, dll, header, linker, .lib

I am trying to create a .dll file from my header and library files that I got from tngaming for their gaming vest.

So far I've been using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but instead of creating a new header file I added my tngaming file to the folder where the header files are located and then added it to the folder inside visual studio by using "Add existing item."

Afterwards I used the properties -> linker -> input where I added my lib file which also seems to work fine.

Then inside the tngaming.cpp i added the line

```
#include "tngaming.h"
```

Now it is possible to build my .dll, but it does not work. When I look at it, there are\ lines that says stuff like "stack memory corrupted" and so on.

Am I creating my .dll correctly or am Idoing something wrong?
How do I actually create my .dll?

Comment: When i compile it comes with the error that it cannot run, but it shouldnt be able to since theres no main method as i understand? Other than that it doesnt seem like theres any exceptions. Sorry if im a bit noobish but first time i play around with this.

Comment: Messages about "stack corruption" do not have anything to do with building.  You have a bug in your code, most typically caused by writing an array past its end.  Common with a C string for example.  You'll need to fix your code.  The error message tells you where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a guy that had the same problem as myself and fixed it so problem solved. Anyone else getting into that problem can look at

http://waterhobo.com/?p=28

Thanks for the help though